# Salesforce: Any API for getting user information?

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth, user-admin

I am trying to find a way to get the information about the salesforce enterprise user from his auth_token. I want to find the username, email address and role(admin/user) from the auth-token.

Something on the lines of

```
curl -XGET 'https://na1.salesforce.com/Userinfo' -H "Authorization: Bearter token"
```

which would give me the required information

I have been looking at the REST API and MetaData API but did not find anything. Preferably I would want this information from a REST API and not some programmatic API. Any help?

Comment: Can anyone shoot me a example of how to build this GET request and pass that Identity Id into it? Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming you've done OAuth, the OAuth response includes an `id` field with an Identity Service URL - e.g.:

```
{
    "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ",
    "issued_at":"1296458209517",
    "refresh_token":"5Ae...",
    "instance_url":"https://na1.salesforce.com",
    "signature":"0/1...",
    "access_token":"00D..."
}
```

GET this URL, passing the access token, and you'll receive the user info. Note the use of `-L` to follow redirects:

```
$ curl -L -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D...' https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ
{
    "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ",
    "asserted_user":true,
    "user_id":"00550000001fg5OAAQ",
    "organization_id":"00D50000000IZ3ZEAW",
    "username":"user@example.com",
    "nick_name":"user1.2950476911907334E12",
    "display_name":"Sample User",
    "email":"user@example.com",
    "status":{
        "created_date":"2010-11-08T20:55:33.000+0000",
        "body":"Working on OAuth 2.0 article"
    },
    "photos":{
        "picture":"https://c.na1.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F",
        "thumbnail":"https://c.na1.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T"
    },
    "urls":{
        "enterprise":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/{version}/00D50000000IZ3Z",
        "metadata":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/{version}/00D50000000IZ3Z",
        "partner":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/{version}/00D50000000IZ3Z",
        "rest":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/",
        "sobjects":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/sobjects/",
        "search":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/search/",
        "query":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/query/",
        "recent":"https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/recent/",
        "profile":"https://na1.salesforce.com/00550000001fg5OAAQ"
    },
    "active":true,
    "user_type":"STANDARD",
    "language":"en_US",
    "locale":"en_US",
    "utcOffset":-28800000,
    "last_modified_date":"2011-01-14T23:28:01.000+0000"
}
```

[More info on Identity URLs.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&type=5)

Comment: is there now a way to to fetch this identity information for all the users of the enterprise using the admin's auth token? This is required since I do not know the ids of all users to fetch their information. Is there a way to do it via some call that gives the info of all enterprise users?

Comment: `SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Users` will work, but you'll probably want to filter by profile ID or some other criteria. You can then build the ID URL yourself - it is `https://login.salesforce.com/id/[ORG ID]/[USER ID]`

Answer (score 17):

There is an actual endpoint for this now as well: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo`

[See here for the help document](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_userinfo_endpoint.htm)

Answer (score 4):

For Rest API ([Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit](https://github.com/Durgaprasad-Budhwani/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit)), we have created one more API to get current authenticate user information. You can find more details at [link](https://github.com/Durgaprasad-Budhwani/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/commit/248909f57d3f2162fbf37d4b5561bc7ce1cc9b13)

Please let me know in case of any other information required.

Comment: The code comment above the userInfo method really helped in understanding what was supposed to be passed as an argument. Thank You.

Comment: Most welcome contactmatt !!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your OAuth token and are familiar with the REST API. The endpoint to hit is:

```
https://yourinstance./services/data/v46.0/sobjects/User/{ID}
```